# Why i can only save file or create folder at NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I use ASI to download files.
But it only works if I set the path to `NSDocumentDirectory`.

```
NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

I haven't changed any other code, just replaced `NSDocumentDirectory` to
`NSCachesDirectory` or `NSDownloadsDirectory`,and it does not work.

Download progress is 100% and file didn't save.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]
```

works perfect in many projects of mine. I think the problem is in your saving code. Could you show it?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it much easier and write to ANY location.
If you are using ASI, you can download DATA.`(NSData)`
So:

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileMgr createFileAtPath:@"whateverpathyouwant" contents:downloaddata attributes:nil];
```

This only works if you are `jailbroken` I guess.